# Write an ARM assembly program

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> Write an ARM assembly program with the below given instructions
>
> 1. Declare a variable ‘A’ which holds 9950948. Load the value in variable ‘A’ in register R3.
>
>    Copy the last 10 bits of the value stored in R3 into R5, copy the bits from 11 to 20 to R6 and Copy bits 21 t0 32 in R7 and Store the values in a stack in the order R6, R5, R7. (15 points)

*MY CURRENT SOLUTION. When Compiling, line with LSL is skipped. How can that be solved

```
        LDR R0,= A
        LDR R3, [R0]

        MOV R1, 0x000003ff  ; mask for last 10 bits - 1111111111
        AND R5, R3, R1      ; Place BitWise AND into R5

        LSL R2, R2, #10



A DCD 0x97D6E4  ; 9950948
;--------------------------------------
stop   B  stop
       END
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How can this be achieved?

Comment: looks pretty straight forward, just follow the steps.

Comment: how would you do it in any other language, write that program first then translate the steps one at a time to asm.

Comment: there arent "variables" in asm, but you can declare a data value with a label which is the equivalent.

Comment: Yes, declaring label is understood. My challge is copying the last 10 bits in R3 into R5. Then, 11 to 20 in R6, and 21 to 32 in R7

Comment: you understand the AND truth table yes?  anything anded with a one is itself, anything anded with zero is zero.  and then there are instructions to shift bits around.  If you can write it in C then compile it that will generate assembly language which you can examine.  which goes back to write it in a language you know then re-write that in assembly language.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I am familiar with AND truth table. But, I just have no clue on how to even write this in a higher lvl language. I'm a novice (student)

Comment: so if you wanted to isolate bits 3-7 into some other variable in C for example first off write numbers on paper 9876543210   then isolate the bits in question 98[76543]210 since hex is easiest across languages separate that into groups of four bits 98 [7654 3]210 I want to keep 3 - 7 so and those with one  00 1111 1000 so if I and my number with 0xF8 that will isolate/keep bits 3 - 7.  x = y&0xF8;  then if I want to right justify the number (not shown as whether to do that or not) we would need to shift right 3 bits so that bit 3 was in the 0 position y = y >> 3;

Comment: assuming that 900123456 is really 0x900123456  (this assignment is poorly written I would wish for a better school/teacher/book/program). the whole exercise is masking and shifting, masking means isolating bits using the properties of an AND operation, extracting portions of the number moving them to new locations then you get into ORing.

Comment: if you examine the truth table for orring anything orred with a zero is itself anything orred with a 1 is a one.  So similar to and if we had some number with 3 bits we care about 0b0000abc000 and another number with 2 bits we care about 0b00000de, anything orred with zero is itself so orring these two numbers together would result in 0b000abc0de   so by masking using ands with ones where you want to keep the bits, using shifting to move those bits around and orring we can combine that to isolate and relocate bits in numbers.

Comment: most useful programming languages provide masking, shifting and orring, you have to be careful about signed vs unsigned (logical vs arithmetic) do they preserve the sign bit, and its language specific but if your msbit is a zero that is not an issue.  anyway so prototyping and getting the logic right in a language you know, then go through the instruction set documentation to translate each of those individual steps into assembly language then test that if possible (it is possible with simulator/emulators but that may take time to get one running if you dont have a platform already)

Comment: wow very poorly written, what does in a stack in order mean?  in push/pop order or in memory address order?  ahh I think I see what they are doing with the stack order, will let you read the documentation for the instruction set to understand how to do that and how not to do that.  we cant/shouldnt just do your homework for you, doesnt help anyone if we do that, so you need to do the reading and the coding.  most of this is going to be reading.

Comment: likewise we have not been sitting in the classroom with you we dont know what was taught in lecture, etc.....or someone might come along and simply do it for you and there you go...

Comment: oh okay. Let me attempt it, and we can make corrections where necessary.

Comment: In respoonse to earlier question, it's in push order

Comment: The bitfield extract part sounds like a job for `ubfx`.

Comment: `LSL R2, R2, #10` is skipped?  More likely R2 just stays zero because you're not reading any of the registers you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
        LDR R0,= A
        LDR R3, [R0]

        MOV R1, 0x000003ff  ; mask for last 10 bits - 1111111111
        AND R5, R3, R1      ; Place BitWise AND of R3 & R1 into R5

        LSL R2, R1, #10     ; Shift left R1 ten times to capture 11th - 20th bit
        AND R6, R3, R2      ; Place BitWise AND of R3 & R2 into R6

        LSL R4, R2, #10     ; Further Shift R2 left 12 times to capture 21st - 32nd bit
        AND R7, R3, R4      ; Place BitWise AND of R3 & R4 into R7

        LDR R8,=0x20000014
        MOV SP, R8

        STMIA SP!, {R6, R5, R7}



A DCD 0x97D6E4  ; 9950948 - student ID excluding 00's
;--------------------------------------
stop   B  stop
       END
```

Comment: edit that into your question, don't post it as an answer.  Also, make sure you copy/paste it as text into a code-formatting block (triple backticks), not an image.

Comment: read the pseudo code for stmia.  very likely why that question is in there to see if you actually read what is going on.  code does not meet the assignment as written (with respect to the pushes).